# 3D object ist distorted after zoom-out and pan

Tags: vtk

I am using `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera` class to manipulate a 3d model, represented on `vtkRenderer`. During a pan, I realized, if the 3d model is zoomed-out using middle mouse button and a pan is applied afterward using the left mouse button, the 3d model is distorted, so that it becomes almost a straight line. If the model is not zoomed out this issue is not present.

```
void mouseInteraction::OnLeftButtonDown() // Does the pan
{
  vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnMiddleButtonDown();
}

void mouseInteraction::OnLeftButtonUp()
{
  vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnMiddleButtonUp();
}
```

[image]